# How can I debug EF Core migrations add generating wrong codes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I suddenly run into trouble when I execute `dotnet ef migrations add AddPaidBy`. It gives me a migration cs file like:

```
    public partial class AddPaidBy : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            // This is wrong
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "StartTime",
                table: "TourneyScheduledHistory",
                type: "datetime(6)",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

            // This is what I want
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "PaidBy",
                table: "TourneyRegistration",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);
        }
```

where I have no idea why the first statement is generated. The statement is migrated in four migrations before like:

```
        // This is from an old migration
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
                name: "StartTime",
                table: "TourneyScheduledHistory",
                type: "datetime(6)",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
        }
```

The column is already in the database, so when I execute `dotnet ef database update`, it will fail.

My question is, how can I figure out why EF Core is making mistakes? What should I fix to make it work right again?
I am cooperating with another one and we have three environments e.g. three databases. Creating migration on each database performs the same.

Comment: try to check all snapshot files in migrations and general snapshot of migrations, maybe during some merge something went wrong and snapshot is invalid

Comment: _The column is already in the database [...]_ → Where is your column `StartTime` coming from if not from EF Core?

Comment: @mu88 It is from EF Core, by a migration which is 4 previous to current. And when I added the 3 previous migrations, this problem does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

As @kalit mentioned in the comment, I took a look at the `ModelSnapshot.cs` and find it is modified in a merge, where following code is deleted:

```
b.Property<DateTime>("StartTime")
    .HasColumnType("datetime(6)");
```

Restoring this block makes thing well again.